# Do Witch Doctor pets mitigate damage with armor and resistances?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Have you seen the new changes done to the Witch Doctor pets?

They basically gave them a shield that limits the maximum damage they can take per hit, and this max damage is based on the player's armor and resistances.

[Click here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923459/) for more information.

I have 2 questions regarding this matter. Do armor and resistances still apply "regularly" to the pets? I know this doesn't have any effect in Act 3 and 4 Inferno since all of the hits will be above the damage cap anyway, but in the earlier acts it would help mitigate the less-damaging hits.

What I mean is, if a pet has a damage cap of 5000, and he receives a hit for 1000, is that hit mitigated by armor and resistances?

My other question is if pets have different damage caps per resistance? In the explanation Blizz gave it said that pets base their shield off of the player' resistances, but we all know how the player has multiple resistances. My guess is that each resistance gives the pet a different max damage cap value.

So if a Witch Doctor has 100 poison resist and 50 cold resist, the pet would have a max damage cap of 200 for poison attacks and a cap of 400 against cold attacks.

Anyone have any more info on this?

Comment: bleh, maybe I misread the patch, I guess it is reduced before the cap :/

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think you have a point. I bet it is reduced both pre and post cap. Weill wait on someone to confirm this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Near the top of the article you linked it confirms that the first answer is yes.

"Zombie Dogs already inherit Armor and Resistance from their owner"

As far as the second question, it only makes sense for damage to be mitigated based on the appropriate resistance (how else could it work?).  So yes, if you had higher poison resist, the max damage cap would be lower for poison than it would be for cold.

Comment: Thanks, I plan on building an online calculator and just wanted to be 100% sure first.